# Google Search Console API null queries empty response - Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup

Tags: php, google-search-console

I'm extracting Google Search Console reports from the API, and I know that the discrepancies I get VS the data from the GSC interface, are from the queries = null lines.

So for example I get:

- GSC interface reports: 100 impressions, 20 clicks
- GSC API reports: 75 impressions, 10 clicks

So I can confirm discrepancy it is coming from the query=null lines because I connect GSC on Google Data Studio and if I filter those, I get the exact same data.

So I'm trying to get those query=null data from the API, but no success at all...

```
$filter_group = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup;

//$groups = array(\['device', 'mobile', 'equals'\], \['country', 'GBR', 'equals'\]); --\> **WORKS**

//$groups = array(\['device', 'desktop', 'equals'\]); --\> **WORKS**

$groups = array(\['query', null, 'equals'\]);  --\> **DOESN'T WORK**

$groups = array(\['query', '', 'equals'\]);  --\> **DOESN'T WORK**

$filters = array();`
```

If anyone can send me some light, I'd be grateful :)

Btw, I'm using PHP, but if have a kind of solution for python or other, maybe that could help me too finding the way...

My original Google Search Console API code, works perfectly filtering on device, country, etc. But if I want to retrieve the query=null data, it doesnt work at all (and the default API report doesn't give you that data)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that trying to look empty query the best way. Becaurse how many page you will see with empty query on google.com (it is what about Google Search Console). But

It seems like you're trying to retrieve data from Google Search Console (GSC) API where the query is null or empty. The reason your current approach doesn't work is because GSC API doesn't directly support filtering by empty queries in the same way you can filter by other dimensions like device or country.

To work around this limitation, you can retrieve all the data from the GSC API and then filter it in your code to identify the rows where the query is null or empty. Here's a general approach in PHP to do this:
/ Your GSC API query to retrieve data (replace with your actual query)
$gscData = $service->searchanalytics()->query($siteUrl, $request);

```
// Initialize an array to store rows with null/empty queries
$nullQueryData = array();

// Loop through the rows in the GSC data
foreach ($gscData['rows'] as $row) {
    // Check if the query is null or empty
    if (empty($row['keys'][0])) {
        $nullQueryData[] = $row;
    }
}
```

// $nullQueryData now contains the rows where the query is null or empty

In this code, we first retrieve all the data from the GSC API and then iterate through each row to check if the query is null or empty. If it is, we add that row to the $nullQueryData array.

Keep in mind that fetching all the data and then filtering it in your code can be less efficient if you have a large dataset, but it's a workaround for cases where GSC API doesn't provide direct support for filtering by null or empty queries.

If you prefer to use Python, you can apply a similar logic using the Google API Client Library for Python to retrieve and filter the data. The key is to fetch all the data and then perform the filtering in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Hoo1y, but there are actually plenty of null query lines on Google Search Console (called Anonymized queries) which have clicks and impressions but don’t have a query. 

I’ll give a try to your code anyways and let you know

Comment: please correct the typos